# bc (standard_in) 1: syntax error

Tags: c, bash, shell, bc

I am trying to find the location of `myfunc` in the executable of:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void myfunc(){
    printf("Hello");
}

int main(){

}
```

I wrote this script:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
start=$(nm -S a.out|grep -w _start)
start_addr=$(echo $start | awk '{print $1}')
myfun=$(nm -S a.out|grep $1)
myfun_addr=$(echo $myfun | awk '{print $1}')
myfun_length=$(echo $myfun | awk '{print $2}')
echo $myfun_length
myfun_end=$(echo "obase=16;ibase=16;$myfun_addr + $myfun_length" | bc)
offset=$(echo "obase=16;ibase=16;$myfun_addr - $start_addr" | bc)
```

The last line runs, but the line before it no:

```
++ echo 'obase=16;ibase=16;0000000000400900 + 00000000000000bc'
++ bc
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
+ myfun_end=
++ echo 'obase=16;ibase=16;0000000000400900 - 0000000000400710'
++ bc
+ offset=1F0
```

Comment: I really want to know the reason of the downvote. This is the first time I use `bc`. The two lines looks almost the same, both have valid variables. Many environments accept both upper- and lowercase hex numbers. So please, explain why you voted this question down.

Comment: Just a guess for downvote: no C involved in either the question or possible answers.

Comment: Unlike other Stackexchange sites, here are some really bitchy users.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hexadecimal numbers in bc are represented with UPPERCASE letters.

Try adding `tr` to some pipe

```
... | tr "a-z" "A-Z" | ...
```

Do not use IBASE and OBASE, these need to be lowercase.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to use `bc`. You can specify hexadecimal values for the standard `$((...))` expression, then use `printf` to output in hexadecimal.

```
start=$(nm -S a.out | grep -w _start)
start_addr=${start%% *}   # Shorter, more efficient
myfun=$(nm -S a.out | grep "$1")
read myfun_addr myfun_length rest <<< "$myfun"  # Shorter, more efficient
echo $myfun_length
myfun_end=$(( 0x$myfun_addr + 0x$myfun_length ))
printf -v offset "%x" $(( 0x$myfun_addr - 0x$start_addr" ))
```

Comment: `$((0x...))` works for hex string in 64 bits integers only.  `bc` is able to perform big integer calculation.